# Select one record from Userform listbox with same ID, and only edit values in selected record

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I'm 95% complete on my workbook, and I run into new problem. Screen shot of situation: **https://ibb.co/Z6dZN18**

Intro: I have Userform for situations like this with listbox, when I enter ID for search in Txtbox7 label ID, search results are shown in listbox.

Next when I dbl_click on desired search result I populate corresponding text boxes. Problem happens when I issue partial amount of some product that have ID 35 for example. On stocks I have 500 units of that product (ID 35) and I need to give 300 units. When I generate new transfer record in second worksheet "Izdato" I have Product ID 35 with 300 units, and in first sheet "RM"  ID 35 have 200 units (500-300=200).

Couple days later, when I give them remaining 200 units, I will create a new record on sheet "Izdato" with same ID 35, bcs its the same product, and I can't sum those quantities in same (row) record because of transfer history, and that works like intended.

Here comes my problem, sometimes I need to return issued amounts from sheet "Izdato" back to sheet "RM" and when I dbl_click on record in listbox which I want to return and set quantity to 0 (zero) because it's returned. Excel change quantity value for all records that have same ID, and I want only to change selected record.

In screenshot link above, in orange filled row I want to set quantity  to zero, because it return 200 units to storage. And when I do that via userform I change value in green filled row, because it have same ID and I don t want that to happen.

Is there any way to prevent that from happening without changing ID number? If it's of any good, I use this code for search and display data in listbox:

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets("Izdato")
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim p As Long
Me.ListBox1.Clear
'code for header
Me.ListBox1.AddItem "ID"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = "Box number"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = "Name"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = "Quantiy"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = "Measurment"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = "Status"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = "Date of return"
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 7) = "Note"
For i = 1 To sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To Len(sh.Cells(i, 1))
p = Me.TextBox7.TextLength
If LCase(Mid(sh.Cells(i, 1), x, p)) = Me.TextBox7 And Me.TextBox7 <> 
 ""Then
With Me.ListBox1
.AddItem sh.Cells(i, 1)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = sh.Cells(i, 2)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = sh.Cells(i, 3)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = sh.Cells(i, 4)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = sh.Cells(i, 5)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = sh.Cells(i, 10)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 7) = sh.Cells(i, 13)
.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = sh.Cells(i, 9)
End With
End If
Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

Once again, thanks in advance!

Comment: Add another column in `ListBox1` to hold the value of `i`, the source row of the data. Also you can probably get rid of the `For x = 1 To Len(sh.Cells(i, 1))` loop using `if sh.Cells(i, 1) Like "*" & Me.TextBox7 & "*"`.

Comment: Can u tell me how to get row number in this case its row number 40, where is selected record? how to match row number with search result?

Comment: Add `.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 8) = i` and then if you want to set the quantity value to zero you have the row without searching for it. You need to add a suitable header like `Src Row`.

Comment: I figure it out, now i have row number  displayed in list box.  I now need  thnk  how to use it to tell excel which row to edit from Userform ..  Btw i coulnd t set header right, so i used this method to make header...

Comment: Its done, i added new textbox that display row number for each ID duplicate, and based on that number i return all values from that row. Thanks for hint and help :D